# Network issues on 14.10 with RTL8111

Tags: networking, 14.10

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my desktop computer in the office, but I'm having troubles with the network. The issue is that I can't make it connect to the network at all, as it displays icon for the WiFi connection and start connecting with it, and when it realizes that there is no WiFi, it sort of connects to wired Connection.

I have tried reinstalling network package that comes with installation, but nothing changed. As this is secondary system, primary is Windows 7, I can ask questions from it. My motherboard is Gigabyte 970A-DS3P with Realtek Ethernet controller.

Here is `lshw` for network:

```
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: eth0
version: 06
serial: fc:aa:14:21:17:62
size: 100Mbit
capacity: 1Gbit
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit
resources: irq:73 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe800fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff

ifconfig:

eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fc:aa:14:21:17:62
inet6 addr: fe80::feaa:14ff:fe21:1762/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:50 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:3572 (3.5 KB)  TX bytes:180 (180.0 B)

lo

Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:11265 (11.2 KB)  TX bytes:11265 (11.2 KB)



$ ls -al /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 феб 28 15:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 феб 28 15:29 ..
-rw------- 1 root root  218 феб 28 15:29 Wired connection 1
```

Comment: Have you configured the IP address or you are using DHCP? Please add the output of `sudo lshw -c network` and `ifconfig` to your question.

Comment: Can you connect an ethernet cord temporarily and see if it works?

Comment: I am using DHCP and on Windows internet works just fine. I have also tried live demo for Linux Mint and it also does not recognize network. If someone can help, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -al /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, had too much work to do. Updated original post with data you asked.

Comment: As much as I can see, there are a lot of issues with the Ethernet Controller I also have. As you can see from the above, it is RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller. I spent last few days searching for an answer, but nothing helped for now.

Comment: While commenting back to someone please prepend `@` to his/her name otherwise he won't be notified....i did not get your late responses :/

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue after several days of torment. Here is what to do:

1. **Get the requirements**
   To build and install the driver, we need the kernel headers and the build tools like gcc. 
   If you have any sort of connection, download them from terminal by using:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```

   Otherwise, download them from some other place and use some media to get them on computer.
2. **Get the driver**
   Now, go to the official download page from Realtek for the Linux/UNIX Driver for the RTL8111/RTL8168 ethernet card and download the latest driver version from the [Realtek Download Page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2)
3. **Untar the archive**
   The driver is compressed to an archive. So uncompress it with the following command:

   ```
   tar xfvj r8168-8.025.00.tar.bz2
   ```

   NOTE: Please do not forget to replace the `r8168-8.025.00.tar.bz2` with the driver version you have downloaded!
4. **Blacklist old driver**
   We have to blacklist the old driver (r8169) to prevent the system to load it. To do this, easily set a new entry in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` which will say:

   ```
   blacklist r8169
   ```

   or just enter in the terminal

   ```
   echo "blacklist r8169″ | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
5. **Build and install the new driver**
   Now, the whole requirements to install the new driver are done. Let us now change in the driver directory, which we have uncompressed in a few steps before:

   ```
   cd r8168-8.025.00
   ```

   NOTE: Again, please do not forget, to change `r8168-8.025.00` to the version you downloaded.

   The only thing we have to do now is, to build the driver and install it. To build it, just type:

   ```
   make clean modules
   ```

   after a few seconds (depending on your CPU), the driver is built and you can install it with:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
6. **Welcome r8168**
   We need to let the system know about the r8168 driver. With the command

   ```
   depmod -a
   ```

   you rebuild the kernel module dependencies and with an

   ```
   sudo modprobe ./src/r8168.ko
   ```

   you insert the new kernel module (the driver) into the kernel.
7. **Make it available for boot**
   To always use the new module, you have to make a new initrd boot file. Just do

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
   ```

   in a terminal. Here we make the initrd file with the help of the `uname -r` command, which allows us to get the version of the actually running kernel.

   Otherwise, you could add the module to `/etc/modules`: simply add a line `r8168` to get the driver automatically loaded after boot. You can do this with only one command:

   ```
   echo "r8168″ | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
   ```

After the reboot you can check if the right driver is loaded with this command:

```
lspci -v
```

with this command you should find your RTL8111/RTL8168 network card in a list and the additional line `Kernel driver in use: r8168`.

Guide has been taken from [this page](https://unixblogger.wordpress.com/2011/10/18/the-pain-of-an-realtek-rtl8111rtl8168-ethernet-card/).