# Ethernet connected , Internet not connecting in Ubuntu 14.04,16.04,17.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, internet, ethernet

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and that hard disk is corrupted and bought the new replacement hard disk. So, I have installed the new Ubuntu 17.04 and Ethernet driver is not picking up. I cannot use Wireless adapter as of now or I cannot get the temporary internet connection. System is saying Connection Established, no Internet connection.

Steps I have done so far from researching the Internet are as follows:

```
Step 1:  Disabled the IPV6 (NOT WORKING) 
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sh -c "echo 'net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
sudo sysctl -p
sudo sed -i 's/false/true/g' /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
sudo reboot -i NOW

Step 2: /etc/udev/rules/d/70.persistant.rules ( NOT WORKING)
Removed or commented the last line, Still not working 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0b:ab:6a:6b:a9", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

Step 3: Removed the Kernel ethernet driver : ( NOT WORKING ) 
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove r8168-dkms 
Reinstalled the r8168 drivers 


Step 4: user@userx:~$ dmesg | grep enp3s0
[    0.878403] r8168 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[   13.088708] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   13.089130] enp3s0: 0xffffb0ec4003d000, 2c:4d:54:d1:dd:55, IRQ 121
[   13.142035] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready
[   17.240967] r8168: enp3s0: link up
[   17.240984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
```

user@userx:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

```
user@userx:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:8677]
    Kernel driver in use: r8168
```

I have reinstalled Operating system twice and changed the Operating system 14.04,16.04.

Step 5 : Changed the BIOS settings , Turned off the secured boot

```
Step 6 : /etc/log/syslog
Jun  9 06:03:51 userx dbus-daemon[1310]: Activating service name='com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Music'
Jun  9 06:03:51 userx dbus-daemon[1310]: Successfully activated service 'com.canonical.Unity.Scope.Music'
Jun  9 06:03:52 userx unity-music-dae[2369]: rhythmbox-collection.vala:510: Unable to open album-art DB!
Jun  9 06:03:52 userx unity-music-dae[2369]: rhythmbox-collection.vala:574: Error while parsing rhythmbox DB: Error opening file /home/user/.local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml: No such file or directory
Jun  9 06:04:01 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:04:21 userx nm-connection-e[2399]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jun  9 06:04:24 userx zeitgeist-daemon[2018]: #033[31m[00:34:24.646483 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Jun  9 06:04:25 userx nm-applet[1751]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jun  9 06:05:15 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:05:25 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:05:36 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:05:52 userx gnome-terminal-[2254]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x55fe562f18a0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Jun  9 06:05:52 userx gnome-terminal-[2254]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x55fe562f18a0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Jun  9 06:06:00 userx nm-applet[1751]: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Jun  9 06:06:00 userx hud-service[1914]: #033[31mvoid DBusMenuImporter::slotGetLayoutFinished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher*)#033[0m: "No such interface 'com.canonical.dbusmenu' on object at path /org/ayatana/bamf/window/25165832"
Jun  9 06:06:47 userx gnome-terminal-[2254]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x55fe562f18a0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Jun  9 06:06:48 userx gnome-terminal-[2254]: Allocating size to GtkBox 0x55fe562f18a0 without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). How does the code know the size to allocate?
Jun  9 06:07:54 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:08:04 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  384.830131] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  384.970808] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=55a5
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  384.970812] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  384.970814] usb 1-3: Product: Cruzer U
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  384.970816] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  384.970818] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 4C530011771209108083
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3"
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  385.058824] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  385.059062] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  385.059212] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jun  9 06:08:11 userx kernel: [  385.070110] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.087843] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer U         1.27 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.088820] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.090017] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 31266816 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.091918] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.091922] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.092346] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.101860]  sdb: sdb1
Jun  9 06:08:12 userx kernel: [  386.104478] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jun  9 06:08:13 userx kernel: [  386.385744] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Jun  9 06:08:13 userx udisksd[1781]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /media/user/UBUNTU-SERV on behalf of uid 1000
Jun  9 06:08:15 userx systemd-timesyncd[745]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jun  9 06:09:09 userx dbus[790]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jun  9 06:09:09 userx systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun  9 06:09:10 userx dbus[790]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun  9 06:09:10 userx systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun  9 06:09:12 userx gvfsd[1410]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Jun  9 06:09:19 userx gvfsd[1410]: message repeated 12 times: [ mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied]
Jun  9 06:09:24 userx gvfsd[1410]: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out
Jun  9 06:09:24 userx gvfsd-network[2532]: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jun  9 06:09:25 userx gvfsd-network[2532]: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
Jun  9 06:09:28 userx nautilus[2557]: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Jun  9 06:09:28 userx nautilus[2557]: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
```

Please help me to connect to the Internet using Ethernet in Ubuntu.

Comment: just a dumb question  ... did you make sure that the cable is fully connected and that it is good? (try another cable)

Comment: What's the output of `ifconfig` when Ethernet cable is plugged?

Comment: The program is not installed, You can install it by typing install net-tools . This is the message I'm getting if I type.

Comment: Tried many links from the morning to evening . Still couldnt figure out what is happening with my system . Please help me .
[link]https://askubuntu.com/questions/591446/network-issues-on-14-10
[link]https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1022411 . I have tried the above links without success .

Comment: I can't help myself to fix this issue , Is anyone out there to fix this issue .